# Why is there a discontinuity on the principal branch of the complex logarithm?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help me understand why there is a discontinuity on the principal branch of the complex logarithm? Also, I would like to take this opportunity to ask for your way of thinking about discontinuities when it comes to complex branches

Comment: Please don't use pictures.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.

Comment: It is caused by the need to specify *some* half-open interval for the *principal* argument of $z = re^{i\alpha}$.  One plausible choice is $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi.$  So, the principal argument of $z$ is the unique value $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$ such that $\theta \equiv \alpha \pmod{2\pi}.$  Under this particular (arbitrary) convention, in any small neighborhood around (for example) $z_1 = -1 = e^{i\pi}$, there will be an element $z$ whose principal argument is arbitrarily close to $-\pi.$

Comment: Any vertical line on this [plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function) provides multiple values for the imaginary part of the complex logarithm distant of $2 \pi n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is $\log(z) = \log |z| + i \theta$ for $\theta$ the argument of $z$. But the function $z \mapsto \theta$ is not continuous since if you move $z$ in a circle around the origin, starting on the positive real axis, then $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $2 \pi$. Then when you hit the positive real axis the second time you assign the value $2 \pi$ to a  point that was originally assigned $0$.

We want the log function to be holomorphic so it must be continuous. To prevent the above discontinuity we usually remove a ray from the origin from the domain. In particular the negative real axis.